# Getting parameter from asynchronous HTTP POST call in PHP

Tags: php, http, crud

I'm trying to integrate a virtual paying system from a bank into my website.

The bank system makes an asynchronous HTTP call to a URL that I define (a PHP document), and from there I try to get the order ID and mark the order as paid.

The problem I'm facing, is that with only the HTTP call I don't seem to be able to get this ID parameter, as the expected result (the couchdb documnt is marked as payed) is not there.

But, when I browse to my document and I paste after it the content of the HTTP call, then it works, like so:

`http://example.com/crud.php?Ds_SignatureVersion=xxx&Ds_MerchantParameters=xxx&Ds_Signature=xxx`

On my `crud.php` I do the following:

```
$test = $_GET['Ds_MerchantParameters'];
```

Why am I managing to get this parameter when I browse to the URL, but not when the bank system makes the HTTP POST call?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the parameter is posted and you try to get it from `$_GET`? Try `$_POST` instead, or to be able to use both methods, `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @KarstenKoop put is as answer and I mark as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bank system issues a POST request to your site, the passed parameters are not in `$_GET`, but in `$_POST`. So change

```
$test = $_GET['Ds_MerchantParameters'];
```

to

```
$test = $_POST['Ds_MerchantParameters'];
```

If you want to be able to use both GET and POST requests for the page, you can also use $_REQUEST:

```
$test = $_REQUEST['Ds_MerchantParameters'];
```